# Convert Windows FTP script to WinSCP script

Tags: windows, batch, ftp, winscp

I currently use the following script to batch send a file to multiple servers. All the servers use the same login credentials. How can I convert this to use in WinSCP, mainly to enable better logging to know when a server is unreachable/ file cannot be uploaded?

transfer.bat

```
@echo off
set LOGFILE=log.log
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%
exit /B

:LOG
ftp -s:u.ftp 1.1.1.1
ftp -s:u.ftp 1.1.1.2 
ftp -s:u.ftp 1.1.1.3
ftp -s:u.ftp 1.1.1.4
ftp -s:u.ftp 1.1.1.5
```

u.ftp

```
username
password
asc
put file.txt
quit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
@echo off
set WINSCP=winscp.com /ini=nul /log=log.log /script=script.txt /parameter
%WINSCP% 1.1.1.1
%WINSCP% 1.1.1.2
%WINSCP% 1.1.1.3
```

With `script.txt` containing:

```
open ftp://username:password@%1%
put -transfer=ascii file.txt
exit
```

Some references:

- [Upload to multiple servers / Parametrized script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_multiple_servers)
- [WinSCP script arguments](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#arguments)
- [Converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

Comment: You can also try: `for %%i in (1.1.1.1,1.1.1.2,1.1.1.3)do %WINSCP% %%i`